# Proving $\big\{\frac{1}{n}\big\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ doesn't converge with respect to the metric $d(x,y)=1 \iff x\neq y$ and $d(x,y)=0$ otherwise

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I proved this statement via contradiction. Assume there is some $a\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\big\{\frac{1}{n}\big\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\longrightarrow a$ with respect the metric $d$ defined in the title. This guarantees we can find $N>0$ so that $d\Big(\frac{1}{n},a\Big)<\frac{1}{2}$ for any  positive integer $n$ larger than $N$. Take $n_1,n_2$ as any two *distinct* positive integers larger than $N$. It follows from triangle inequality that $$\begin{eqnarray*}1&=&d\Bigg(\frac{1}{n_1},\frac{1}{n_2}\Bigg) \\ &\leq& d\Bigg(\frac{1}{n_1},a\Bigg)+d\Bigg(\frac{1}{n_2},a\Bigg) \\ &<& \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \\ &=& 1\end{eqnarray*}$$ which is a contradiction. How does this look? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks fine. I would do it as follows: if $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to $a$, I would take $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies d\left(\frac1n,a\right)<1$. But then $n\geqslant N\implies\frac1n=a$, which is impossible, since $\frac1N\ne\frac1{N+1}$.

Comment: Thanks. It's quite clear to me that any sequence convergent sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with respect to the metric $d$ would necessarily be eventually constant simply by taking $\epsilon=1$. But you're sure there is no mistake in my argument? The provided answer was marked as incorrect.

Comment: Your proof is correct. Furthermore, it's an unorthodox proof (in the good sense), whereas my proof is banal.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you are working with the discrete metrics. You can generalize the result in a general topological space:

> If $X$ is a disrete topological space and $\{ x_n\}$ is a sequence in $X$ such that $x_i \neq x_j, \; \forall i\neq j$, then $\{ x_n\}$ diverges.

This happens because in a discrete space every singleton is an open set. So, suppose that $\{ x_n\}$ converges to $a\in X$. Then the open neighborhood $\{ a\}$ should contain all but finitely terms of the sequence $\{ x_n\}$, i.e. $\exists n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n=a, \; \forall n>n_0$ which contradicts the condition $x_i \neq x_j, \; \forall i\neq j$.